# GROUP BY and HAVING in SQL

Tags: sql

If I write

```
SELECT continent FROM world GROUP BY continent HAVING sum(population) >= 100000000
```

it will return all continents that have a total sum over 100 million. But if I leave out the GROUP BY like so

```
SELECT continent FROM world HAVING sum(population) >= 100000000
```

it will only return one continent (in this case Asia).

Why is that?

Comment: Because it performs `sum` for the whole dataset: you did not specify `GROUP BY` explicitly, so it's grouped by the whole data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't have `GROUP BY`, aggregate functions like `SUM()` operate over the entire table, treating it all as one big group. That's why you just get one row of results.

When you use an aggregate function, it's not technically valid to return any columns in the `SELECT` list other than those in the `GROUP BY` clause, so your query isn't valid SQL. Some databases, such as MySQL, allow returning other columns as an extension; in that case, it selects the values from arbitrary rows in the group. And if there's no `GROUP BY` clause at all, the entire table is one group, so you get the `continent` column from some random row in the table.